# SQL Plus XML parser doesn't allow å ä ö

Tags: sql, xml, xml-parsing, sqlplus, oracle-sqldeveloper

I got a table containing XMLType. My tags contains Å and Ö, example "ÅR"
I have parsed it using Oracle SQL Developer, but once i try to use the same query in Sql Plus it doesnt accept å ä ö. Don't know how to solve this..

So in the terminal this (raw or in a .sql file)

```
select count(d.year)
from fic data, XMLTable('/Arkiv/Record'             
PASSING data.xmldata                
COLUMNS             
YEAR    varchar2(20)    PATH    'ÅR'
) d where data.id =7;
```

Will give the following error:

```
ORA-19114: XPST0003 - error during parsing the XQuery expression:
LPX-00800: XQuery invalid token ''
1   ÅR
-  ^
```

Comment: Unsure if you can use entity references in paths, but try `PATH '&#xC5;R'`...?

Comment: Nope, HTML codes does not work

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the encoding in the terminal? Or SQL Plus..

Comment: How about `PATH UNISTR('\00C5R')`?

Comment: EvilBob22, nope.
chcp 1252 in windows prompt solved the problem in windows, but I couldn't solve it in linux prompt

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is an issue of sqlplus (or the shell you're calling it from) supplying the data in the wrong encoding.

replace the non-ascii-chars in your literals with `UTL_I18N.raw_to_char ( HEXTORAW ( '<character_as_octet_sequence>' ), '<charset_encoding>' )`. This will convert the chars into the database charset and should pass through any tool in between as you only need us-ascii symbols for specification.

in your example:

- A circonflex -> `UTL_I18N.raw_to_char ( HEXTORAW ( 'C5' ), 'WE8ISO8859P15' )`
- O umlauted   -> `UTL_I18N.raw_to_char ( HEXTORAW ( 'D6' ), 'WE8ISO8859P15' )`

Comment: Yep, seems its the shell im calling from, chcp 1252 solved it in Windows but I didnt find any good solution for Linux terminal

Comment: the suggested method works under any os. note: you do not have to know the hex encoding in the charset your shell is using, only in _some_ charset oracle knows about. evilbob22's variation will work too, however, the docs say that `UNISTR` converts into the national charset and not the db charset.